# AtTask (Workfront) External Page: Send parameter to external server

Tags: attask

I need to display some external data related to a task inside Workfront. I can create a dashboard that displays a static "External Page" from a private local server. I need to pass a parameter in that URL that includes some information about the current task, so I can get a response from a local ERP database that is relevant to that task (a field in my ERP system is used to relate quotes/orders/invoices to Workfront tasks). For example, I would have to define a URL that would look something like http://my.intranet/report?ref=$$REFNUM ... And the $$REFNUM token would be replaced with the reference number for the task where the dashboard is located. My server would see a request that looks like http://my.intranet/report?ref=12345, and return information related to the task with reference number 12345.

I have proposals from two consultants that suggest that this is possible, but I can find no documentation that explains how to pass dynamic information out in an External Page URL. Any suggestions?

UPDATE: With some additional hacking, I've discovered that I can get a Session ID returned using the following syntax:

```
some.url/query?session={!$$SESSION}
```

and I can get User ID using this syntax:

```
some.url/query?userid={!$$USER.ID}
```

I have not yet been successful getting task related detail. {!$$TASK.ID} returns null, whether called from the dashboard creation page, or from a tab embedded on a Task layout.

Are there any other secret wildcard variables and how to use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution was found. The following syntax will cause Workfront to return the Session and ID of the object from which it is called:

```
some.url/query?session={!$$SESSION}&object={!ID}
```

These objects can be used in an API call to get other information related to the object, such as referenceNumber. Credit goes to this page from AtAppStore, which is where I found the syntax.
http://store.atappstore.com/index.php/executive-summary/

Comment: I developed an integration between Epicor 9.05 and Workfront using this solution. It is posted here in case it may be useful to someone. [workfrontEpicorLink.py on Github](https://github.com/cbonsig/workfrontEpicorLink)

Comment: The link is broken (404).

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime Adobe bought Workfront and our company started using it.

I spent few days online trying to find a solution for the same problem.

On the end this is what I came up with (these are focused to render values on WF TASK object view, and other objects will give different result or no result):

I also answered the same question on: https://one.workfront.com/s/question/0D54X00006pnbPvSAI/how-tp-pass-wildcards-as-url-parameter-to-external-pages

```
taskID={!ID}
taskURL={!URL}
taskDuration={!Duration}
taskName={!Name}
taskDescription={!Description} - (breaks if it includes HTML)
taskStatus={!Status}
taskPriority={!Priority}
taskProgressStatus={!Progress Status}
taskPercentComplete={!Percent Complete}
taskPlannedHours={!Planned Hours}
taskProjectedCompletionDate={!Projected Completion Date}
taskRefNumber={!Reference Number}
taskNumber={!Task Number}
taskHasDocuments={!Has Documents}
projectName={!Project} OR {!Project.Name}
projectID={!Project ID} OR {!Project.ID} - (In PROJ object one gives a value but other one renders null)
assignedToID={!Assigned To.ID}
assignedToName={!Assigned To.Name}
assignedToFirstName={!Assigned To.FirstName}
assignedToLastName={!Assigned To.LastName}
assignedToEmail={!Assigned To.Email Address}
assignedToUsername={!Assigned To.Username}
sessionID={!$$SESSION}
userID={!$$USER.ID}
userName={!$$USER.Name}
userFirstName={!$$USER.First Name}
userLastName={!$$USER.Last Name}
userEmail={!$$USER.Email Address}
userUsername={!$$USER.Username}
userRoleID={!$$USER.Role ID}
enteredByID={!Entered By ID}
hasMessages={!Has Messages}
hasNotes={!Has Notes}
hasReminderNotifications={!Has Reminder Notifications}
iterationID={!Iteration ID}
lastConditionNoteID={!Last Condition Note ID}
lastNoteID={!Last Note ID}
numberOfChildren={!Number of Children}
securityRootObjCode={!securityRootObjCode}
securityRootID={!securityRootID}
submittedByID={!Submitted By ID}
version={!Version}
trackingMode={!Tracking Mode}
lastNote={!Last Note}
parent={!Parent}
objID={!ObjID} - (Will give some ID on Dashboard view)

There are a few more like {!Planned Cost}, {!Revenue Type} etc.
```

I wanted to get objectType or objCode of current WF object in the iframe src call so I could drop 1 to 2 API queries on the target page.

It turned out you cannot do that.

But I can get securityRootObjCode.

And that allows me to do:

If current WF object is TASK then {!securityRootObjCode} will render PROJ, {!Project} will NOT be null and {!Project ID} will *not* be null.

If current WF object is PROJ then {!securityRootObjCode} will render null, {!Project} will be null and {!Project ID} will *not* be null.

If current WF object is Dashboard all values will be null.

Comment: The one.workfront.com link is (effectively) broken. It redirects to a generic page.