# Is there a way to include external app in workfront via iframe or something similar?

Tags: attask, workfront-api

We have developed a little custom web application that uses the Workfront REST API to pull data from Workfront. We have recently received a request from the users to integrate this application "as another tab" in Workfront. I have scanned through all the documentation I can find and I don't see a way to do this in Workfront. The closest thing I have found is Webhooks but I don't think that is going to do what we want. Am I missing something? Does anyone know if this is even possible?

Comment: This is very similar to a discussion that took place at last week's Workfront LEAP user conference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is absolutely possible, though it may be tricky based on the amount of customization you have.

Step 1: Create a new dashboard and add an external page to it - this is the URL to your webapp.

Step 2: Create a new layout template or modify an existing layout template and add a custom tab wherever you need it (projects, tasks, global, etc.) that will load your new dashboard.

Step 3: Assign your layout template to users based on their group, team, or individual users. note that layout templates will apply with an order of precedence so your new template may be overridden if another has higher precedence or the user created their own layout template.

Comment: It looks like the external page has to be accessible externally, as in not behind our firewall. Is that true?

Comment: And I found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28843813/attask-workfront-external-page-send-parameter-to-external-server) that shows a way to pass parameters. The big question: is the SESSIONID enough for me to request data via the Workfront API?

Comment: Yes, the page must be accessible externally. You can find the IP range of your Workfront cluster (CL01-04) and whitelist those, which should minimize your security risk but you will have to make some allowances.

Yes, passing your sessionID is enough to execute queries, but you may want to build a new account with sysadmin rights and use its API key if you want to be able to perform privileged operations that may be above your user's access level.